# GWT application deployed locally to Intellij Tomcat does not see breakpoints in gwt-aware client-module

Tags: debugging, tomcat, intellij-idea, gwt

Some facts about the application:

- It consists of several modules, one of which is a GWT client module
- Spring 3
- GWT 2.6.1 (+ compatible GXT)
- Is packaged as .war and can be deployed to a standalone Tomcat
- Chrome add-on does not work anymore, so until recently I had to rely on Eclipse + embedded Jetty + Firefox 24 to be able to launch the app in DevMode and debug it

The other day I decided to try to launch it in IntelliJ IDEA and see if the debugging would work there.

Observations after deploying the app via a `local Tomcat` configuration in IntelliJ:

- The app is deployed just fine (wither using `war` or `exploded war` artifact). Basically, Intellij takes the `work` directory from the standalone Tomcat installation and moves it into its installation folder (eg. `.IntelliJIdea2019.1/system/Tomcat/Unnamed_MYAPP`). Config files get also copied to the `config` dir.
- The `webapps` dir of Tomcat stays within the original Tomcat installation and the app is deployed there

At first I thought the breakpoints are not recognized at all. However, it turned out that I was testing breaking only within the GWT client module; when I later tried some other module - the execution stopped as expected.

Now, what's interesting is that when I would develop and debug with Jetty, if I made a change to the GWT client-module, I could simply reload the page and it would appear.

With Intellij and Tomcat, it's the opposite. Breakpoints do not work as mentioned, but also refreshing, eg. via `Update classes` (instead of full redeployment) does not work, whereas for the other module it does.

Is there a way to somehow adjust my artifact so that GWT module as well can be debugged?

My `exploded war` artifact looks like this:

- < output root >
- META-INF

  - MANIFEST.MF
- WEB-INF

  - classes

    - GWT module compile output
  - lib
  - web.xml
- webapp directory contents
- GWT client module GWT compiler output

Comment: Please report the issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it was a silly situation - I was expecting the execution to stop at the breakpoints set in the Java code of the gwt-aware module -- but since it was already transpiled to Javascript -- that was impossible.

The only way for breakpoints to stop in such a module is to use the DevMode.